# Drop packet to bridged domU in XenServer

Tags: iptables, xenserver

I have Xenserver in version 7.2 with several VM.

I only have 1 nic (`eth0`). All VM are bridged to `xenbr0`. I would like to drop some type of packet so in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` I added :

```
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 161 -j DROP
```

here is the complete file :

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 161 -j DROP
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
# DHCP for host internal networks (CA-6996)
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 67 --in-interface xenapi -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Linux HA hearbeat (CA-9394)
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 694 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
# dlm
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21064 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 5404,5405 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124624/what-a-input-j-reject-reject-with-icmp-host-prohibited-iptables-line-does-ex#answers-header) that `iptables` is bypassed in bridged environnement, do I need to add this rules explicitly on all `vif` interface ? It doesnt work when I specify `xenbr0` as the interface in `iptables` rule.